# keyboard done key action swift iOS doesn't work

Tags: ios, keyboard, return, swift, action

I'm new in stackoverflow, I have a problem with new swift code.
I have custom the return button on keyboard with "Done", but when I tap on it, don't befall anything... How can I hide the keyboard on tap it? 
I have added a code (found on this site) for hide the keyboard when you tap somewhere ,not in the keyboard, but I can't custom it with tap on "done" button... Thank you before!!

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You need to implement delegate method which is called when you hit done button:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

You also need to conform to UITextFieldDelegate protocol:

```
// I assume you override UIViewController class. If not add UITextFieldDelegate to your class
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

The last thing is set up your class to be a text field delegate:

```
textField.delegate = self
```

Comment: You can also use Xcode to create the connection between your UI and code. See my post below

Comment: I would probably return **false** in there

Answer (score 11):

```
textField.delegate = self
```

can be replaced by 
[image]

This will create the necessary connections between your View, its component and will make the textFieldShouldReturn method work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The protocol methods have new signatures (Swift 4.1). IE:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

As the protocol methods are optional, using a wrong signature will silently fail.

Comment: I would probably return **false** in there