# I want user to login when they press done button on keyboard (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, uibutton, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a UITextfield and a login UIbutton and I want user to be able to log in when Done button is press on the Iphone keyboard.

How can I achieve that

Thanks you very much!!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775678/keyboard-done-key-action-swift-ios-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol on your class, and then use the `textFieldShouldReturn` method to define what should happen when 'Done' is pressed. Something along the lines of:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {  
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    // Do something here
    return true
}
```

You also have to tell the text field that your class instance is its delegate:

```
myTextField.delegate = self
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this its working for me

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtNumber: UITextField!
  override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //--- add UIToolBar on keyboard and Done button on UIToolBar ---//
        self.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()


    }  

  func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
  {
    let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50))
    doneToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default

    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Aceptar", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: Selector("doneButtonAction"))

    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    items.append(flexSpace)
    items.append(done)

    doneToolbar.items = items
    doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

    self.txtNumber.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar

  }

  func doneButtonAction()
  {
    self.txtNumber.resignFirstResponder()
  }
```

https://gist.github.com/jplazcano87/8b5d3bc89c3578e45c3e