# Done button don't work when restricting characters for UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm using below code to restrict users to only use certain characters for a `UITextField`. The allowed characters are within the extension string. It works good but the problem I'm facing is users can't press done button and run my code.

I'm new to swift and stack overflow. I have no clue what to do.

```
extension String {

    var containsValidCharacter: Bool {
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890 -")
        let range = (self as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    }
}


func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return string.containsValidCharacter
}
```

I just want the "**done**" button to work.

Comment: Which done button are you talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keyboard done key action swift iOS doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775678/keyboard-done-key-action-swift-ios-doesnt-work)

Comment: The "done" , "OK" button for the keyboard. If I remove the above code from my project then the OK button for the keyboard works. This is a IOS program.

Comment: Your point is to add done button when the user finishes typing
?

Comment: did you set a delegate of `UITextField` and override `func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{}` in your viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overriding this **UITextFieldDelegate** method.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    return true    
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate)